# list all users on sql to html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I list all users on sql to html page ? I used this code ;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE id<'".$row['id']."'");
$rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die();
echo '<table>
  <tr>
  <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$rowtwo['username'].'</td>
  </tr>
  </table>';
```

NOTE: $row['id'] is current user id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it like this:

get all users from database (in case u will get all, otherwise use your query):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users");
```

each user should be printed in his own row:

```
echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<tr>
        <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$rowtwo['username'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

the While loop is important to get only one row from the database after the other.

Comment: Ok That's really good.Thank you.But what aboout if user image and username, I mean, I have also query for another table that called 'row', how can I create table with use this two query please ?

Comment: sorry, I did not get your question in detail. (1) are u trying to query username and image from table 'Users'?    (2) what are u trying to query from the table 'row'? You should add necessary information and code to your question. If my answer was sufficient, please mark as correct

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547202/users-image-and-username-from-sql-to-html