# users image and username from sql to html

Tags: php, html, sql

I need help to write user image and username from sql to html I tried this codes;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_images WHERE id<'".$id."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE id<'".$id."'");
echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<tr>
    <td><img height="115" width="115" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '"/></td>
    <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$rowtwo['username'].'</td>
    </tr>';}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: What happened? Was there an error?

Comment: Also, it's usually better to store a path to an image and use that, rather than storing the binary information in a field in your db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U should try a join query for username and image, so that u only have to use one query and one mysql_fetch_array()

try it like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.image, u.username FROM tbl_images i JOIN Users u ON u.id=i.id WHERE u.id<'".$id."'");
if(!$query) die("MYSQL: ".mysql_error());     

echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<tr>
    <td><img height="115" width="115" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '"/></td>
    <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color=#EBEBEB>' .$row['username'].'</td>
    </tr>';}
echo '</table>';
```

but is your base64_encode correct? I think it should be decode???

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL ... I get this one.

Comment: I solved the problem it's about WHERE u.id<$id part.. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome! If this answer was sufficient, please mark as correct